# Inscrutible error in plyr: Error in names(result) <- names(pieces) : 'names' attribute [11644] must be the same length as the vector [11187]

Tags: r, debugging, parallel-processing, plyr

I'm getting an error while running `plyr` on a cluster, and I'm having a tough time debugging it.  I'm sharing pseudo-code below.  I run a function called `getopt` wrapped in `Xgetopt`, which handles errors.  It basically does gridsearch optimization on a matrix of inputs, row-wise.  The input matrix is 11644x2.

Can anybody tell me where this error comes from or what it means?  I can't do traceback, because I can't replicate the error locally.

```
> library(plyr)
> library(doMC)
> registerDoMC(32)
> 
> Xgetopt = function(input){
+   out = tryCatch(getopt(input), error=function(e) e, finally=NA)
+   if(inherits(out, "error")) {out=NA;     print("an error happened but it got handled.")}
+   return(out)
+   }
> 
> tocalc = expand.grid(ID = sort(unique(m$model$ID)), price = seq(from=0,to=100,by=2.5))
> tocalc$ID = as.character(tocalc$ID)
> out = dlply(.data=tocalc,c('ID','price'),.fun=Xgetopt,.parallel=TRUE)

[1] "an error happened but it got handled."
[1] "an error happened but it got handled."
[1] "an error happened but it got handled."

snip (only a few errors, mostly successes)

[1] "99 37.5"
Error in names(result) <- names(pieces) : 
  'names' attribute [11644] must be the same length as the vector [11187]
Calls: dlply -> llply
Execution halted
```

Comment: Try the following: Reduce your grid in size to a much smaller object, in such a way that at least on of the rows will generate the error.  Then run the function locally only on this subset and debug locally.

Comment: Like Andrie said;  it appears that somewhere you've not got every element named.

Comment: @Andrie:  this is tough to do because I don't know which rows generate the error, and each optimization takes about 15 seconds -- 50 hours of CPU time for the whole set.  Carl Witthoft:  "Not got every element named?"  Sure, they're all named "out" -- or at least they should be...